# Why do roles and schemas have (mostly) the same name?

Tags: sql-server, users, role

When I create a database and add a user I get an interface with options. On that interface I can choose:

1. Owned Schemas
2. Membership

This question on dba.stackexchange [**HERE**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/difference-between-owned-schemas-and-role-membership-for-microsoft-sql-server) says schemas and roles are not related. This has confused me in the past since they have the same names. Why is this?

Also. In the `Schemas` folder, I see `dbo`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and `sys`. But in the user dialogue, under 'Owned Schemas' I don't see these options. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has confused me in the past since they have the same names. Why is this?

I think this is simply becuase of convention, it is easier to identify the owner of the schema.

Defualt schemas `dbo`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, `sys` schemas are belongs to `dbo`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, `sys` users respectively and these are inherited from `model` database.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `sys` are used to store system objects so that we can't select to store user-defined objects. `dbo` is the default schema so we don't need to select it.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669061(v=vs.110).aspx)